# MeteorJS replacing packages with NPM failures

Tags: meteor, npm, ecmascript-6, undefined-reference, es6-module-loader

I have an app built in MeteorJS that I built on Version 1.2. I've now upgraded to 1.4.0.1 and started moving some dependencies from Atmosphere packages to NPM instead. Some have worked fine, some with headaches but those were top-level ones. I'm now having issues with getting others to work such as the Bootstrap Date Time Picker. I've removed the package:

```
meteor remove tsega:meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker
```

and added the NPM equivalent:

```
npm install --save eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

In my `addEvent.js` client-side template file I've got this at the top:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import moment from 'moment';
import dateTimePicker from 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

Then further down in an `onRendered` block:

```
/* Set instance var */

const instance = this;

/* Date/time picker start */

instance.$('#addDateStart').datetimepicker({
    icons: {
        time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-dot-circle-o'
    },
    format: 'Do MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
    sideBySide: true
});

/* Date/time picker end */

instance.$('#addDateEnd').datetimepicker({
    icons: {
        time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-dot-circle-o'
    },
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'Do MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
    sideBySide: true
});
```

I'm getting an error in the browser console:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41TypeError: instance.$(...).datetimepicker is not a function
at .<anonymous> (addEvent.js:84)
at template.js:119
at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:465)
at fireCallbacks (template.js:115)
at .<anonymous> (template.js:208)
at view.js:107
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
at view.js:106
at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:511)
at onGlobalMessage (setimmediate.js:102)
```

I've tried various things to get this working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there is an issue with the package.

Answer (score 0):

See whether or not `datetimepicker` is part of the jQuery constructor

```
$.prototype.hasOwnProperty("datetimepicker");
```

If not, see if it's on the global object:

```
instance.hasOwnProperty("datetimepicker");
```

If so, add it to the jQuery prototype:

```
$.prototype.datetimepicker = instance.datetimepicker;
```

**References**

- [bootstrap-datetimepicker issue #1662: datetimepicker() is not a function](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1662)
- [bootstrap-datetimepicker issue #1484: export datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1484)